# how to access Dom of a h2 tag inside div in angular 4 Unit Testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

i am new in testing and  trying to Unit Test . i want to access Dom of a 'h2' tag inside the div

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg  am done with access dom of div  by query selector  By css but i want to acess  h2 tag inside div